# Yocto Qt6 build hangs on qtbase do_install_ptest_base

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, yocto

I'm building yocto image (core-image-minimal) with Qt6 on Ubuntu 22.04.3.

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "2.2.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "raspberrypi3"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "4.1.4"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm vfp cortexa7 neon vfpv4 thumb callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "langdale:3e95f268ce04b49ba6731fd4bbc53b1693c21963"
meta-raspberrypi     = "langdale:8e3cbfa598de106a78d9a9e27aa25ded51416896"
meta-oe              
meta-multimedia      
meta-networking      
meta-python          = "langdale:cbbaa82238cd60f08c9b9cb58dde59d5f9318c7b"
meta-qt6             = "6.5:a65fb409f4469c087ae3e23ee80fbb2531f1856e"
```

I added this to my local.conf:

```
MACHINE ?= "raspberrypi3"

PACKAGECONFIG:append = " accessibility eglfs fontconfig gles2 linuxfb tslib gbm"

IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " \
        qtbase \
        qtdeclarative \
        findutils \
        util-linux \
        "
```

I also created qtbase_git.bbappend recipe in my local layer, because before qtbase failed configuration, this helped to pass the configuration task:

```
EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DQT_FEATURE_egl=ON -DFEATURE_opengl=ON -DQT_FEATURE_opengl_desktop=OFF"
```

And I created pointercal_0.0.bbappend and tslib_1.22.bbappend recipes because it was failing without this:

```
BBCLASSEXTEND = "native"
```

The build hangs on qtbase-6.5.4-r0 do_install_ptest_base task at approx 10 min. My computer freezes for a while and then Ubuntu kills the terminal.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like the OOM killer has awaken of its slumber, and went on a rampage (you can confirm/verify this in dmesg). [Get more ram](https://downloadmoreram.com/), or at least a handful of GBs of swap space.

Comment: Yes, indeed, RAM. I already downloaded more RAM but obviously, it wasn't enough. Now with 18GB RAM, it sucessfully finished. Thanks.